# Can't register my package on pypi.org (PIP) with a name released for me by the previous owner

Tags: pip, package, upload, pypi, python-packaging

Can't register my package on pypi.org (PIP) with a name released for me by the previous owner.

The problem described in details here - https://github.com/pypi/support/issues/2738

I asked the previous owner about getting me the name of his abandoned project, and the owner just deleted his project, instead adding me as an owner to his repo, and I can't upload my one because of the next error:

> Response from https://upload.pypi.org/legacy/: 400 The name 'xman' is too similar to an existing project. See https://pypi.org/help/#project-name for more information.

I opened the ticket about 2 months ago and there's still no response. My project is in the state of polishing and preparing documentation, so I would like to release it on PIP soon.

**What can I do to get the desired name in some reasonable time?**

Comment: Looks like you got an answer on the linked github. If choosing the name is against their policy, then there is probably nothing more anyone here can say about it